# Usage of dollar and tilde

Tags: shell

May i know why "`~`" and "`+$`" is used in this shell script.This is a part of script deleting files older than specific days.

```
if ! [[ $FILE_AGE =~ "^[0-9]+$" ]]; then
  usage
  exit 1
```

I am able to understand that this portion of the script is used to check whether we are entering numbers or alphabets.

Comment: You must *not* quote the right-hand side if you're using bash version 4. If it's quoted, bash will interpret it as a literal string. It's not super clearly documented, but [the man page says](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-g_t_005b_005b-57): "Any part of the pattern may be quoted to force it to be matched as a string"

Answer (score 6):

The `=~` operator means "true if string on left matches the regular expression on the right, else false".

`^[0-9]+$` means look for a sequence of one or more (That's the `+`) characters in the range 0 to 9 (that's `[0-9]`) that start the beginning of the string (`^`) and end at the end of the string (`$`).

This is basic bash and regex, consult [the Bash manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

**=~** is a regular expression match

**$** is part of the regular expression `^[0-9]+$` and it means to match the end of the String

Google "regular expressions" for a tutorial or guide

Answer (score 1):

The `=~` is the regex match operator  and the `+` belongs to the pattern `[0-9]+`, not the `$`. 
The condition tests if the value of the variable FILE_AGE matches the pattern `[0-9]+` (one or more digits) between `^` (start of line/string) and `$` (end of line/string).

Answer (score 0):

Google for "Bash script equals tilde operator":

http://unixdog.com/?p=94

As for the dollar sign(s), the first one is because `$FILE_AGE` is a variable in Bash, and the second one is because it's part of the regular expression. Here's a great site on RegEx:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html